# Using SQL Server and Firebird database in a single Android app

Tags: android, sql-server, android-gradle-plugin, firebird

I am trying to connect may android app to sql server and firebird in a single asynctask method. I copied jar files
compile files('libs/jtds-1.3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jaybird-full-2.2.3.jar') in my gradle. Now I got some error like these
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver
  >   File1: /home/hms/Test/app/libs/jaybird-full-2.2.3.jar
  >   File2: /home/hms/Test/app/libs/jtds-1.3.0.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

How can I correct it.

Comment: All JDBC drivers have `/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file. You will need to merge them (or maybe exclude them, not sure if this file is important when using a JDBC driver under Android).

Comment: how can I merge that files.I tried  packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/Service' 

    }under android in gradle but the errors still exist

Comment: I don't do android, so I don't know, sorry.